# Android transfer bitmap origin

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, touch-event

I draw a rectangular bitmap with width 200 and length 100 in size by using canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 100, 50, null). Therefore, the origin of the bitmap is (100,50) on the canvas. When I touch the bitmap on my device screen at the center of the bitmap (200, 100) with MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and set the bitmap origin to the center of the bitmap, the bitmap origin shift from (100, 50) to (200, 100). Is there a way I can transfer the bitmap origin from top/left corner to the center of the bitmap before the ACTION_DOWN event? Or, there is a way I can draw the bitmap with the center of the bitmap? Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: `"When I touch the bitmap on my device screen..."` Well nothing just *happens* when you touch the screen by default -- what are you doing in your `onTouchEvent()` method? If you know the width and height of your bitmap, just shift your x and y coordinates with which you draw the bitmap by half the width and height, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are right! I have edited my question to make it clearer. I did set the bitmap origin on ACTION_DOWN event to the center of the bitmap when I touch my device screen. I would like to know if there is a way I can set the bitmap origin to the center of the bitmap before the ACTION_DOWN event or I can create the bitmap with a center origin but not top/left corner.

Comment: There is no "origin" that you can set. `drawBitmap()` takes an x and y  at which to draw the bitmap, starting from the top left. You can either shift your x and y variables by half the width and height, or you could translate your canvas by that same amount.

Comment: Since I cannot change the bitmap draw point (on top/left corner), I calculate the distance of the touch points and the bitmap top/left corner and use their relative coordinations for ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE events. Now, the bitmap will not JUMP to the touch point from the bitmap draw point when I touch the device screen by reset the bitmap draw point. PROBLEM SOLVED!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the bitmap draw point (on top/left corner) shift (JUMP) from the bitmap draw point to a touch point when I use the touch point to reset the bitmap draw point, I calculate the distance of the touch points and the bitmap top/left corner and use their relative coordinations to reset the bitmap draw point for ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE events. Now, The bitmap draw point will not JUMP when I touch the device screen and can be moved with my finger smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a view for drawing. So you override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` and `onDraw (Canvas canvas)`. In `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)`, you should call `invalidate ()` to trigger `onDraw (Canvas canvas)`. Therefore, from (100, 50) to (200, 100), you just need to draw the bitmap again by the method `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, null)`.

```
float mOriginalX = 100, mOriginalY = 50;

public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
  mOriginalX  = 200;
  mOriginalY  = 100;
  invalidate();
}

protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, mOriginalX, mOriginalY, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, I did not make my queation clear enough. I did re-set the bipmap to the (200, 100) on the ACTION_DOWN event and redraw the bitmap with invalidate(). That is why the bitmap origin jump from (100, 50) to (200, 100) when I touch the center of the bitmap on my device screen. I would like to know if there is a way I can set the bitmap origin to the center of the bitmap before the ACTION_DOWN event or I can create the bitmap with a center origin but not top/left corner.

Comment: do you wanna create a subset of source bitmap? you can use createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter)